# Are there any alternatives to Openfiler that any good?

Tags: linux, nas, openfiler

Does anyone know of any alternatives to Openfiler? I have tried FreeNAS a while ago an was not really impressed, has it changed very much in that last year?

Is there anything else I can look at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use http://www.nexentastor.org at home, and it works nicely.

No experience in openfiler or freenas though, so can't say if its better or worse. Works nicely for me at home on a AMD N36L based box with a LSI 1068e based SAS controller.

Comment: Very interesting, I assume it has a WebGUI?

Comment: Yes, the web gui is the main way to configure it. You can also use a cli app to accomplish the same things, but I actually prefer the web gui.

Comment: very nice, there website is a little weird but i think I downloaded the right thing. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Just remember that nexenta (and nexentastor) are solaris based, you might want to check http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/hcl/ for hardware compatibility, it is quite picky

Comment: OH wow good thing you mentioned that, I would have just dived head first into a whole lot of trouble. The hardware I have probably will not support Solaris, I will have to check.

Comment: I'm using NexentaStor for my NAS, I chose it over FreeNas because it can use ZFS mirrored system drives. I'm using an Atom D525 NM10 based mainboard and it runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a WebUI on top of a Solaris-based distribution, there's the [napp-it](http://www.napp-it.org/index_en.html) project.

[ZFSguru](http://zfsguru.com/) is available if you'd like to use ZFS on FreeBSD.  While the ZFS implementation in FreeBSD isn't as up to date as the one in Solaris (most notably, it's missing support for deduplication), it's part of the core stable OS.  FreeBSD probably has better hardware support than Solaris as well.

Comment: Well to be honest I am not really thrilled about running Solaris anything. I have started down the Linux path and don't need to complicate things for myself even more, I would like to use a Linux solution if possible.